# Returning nil when converting string to date in swift

Tags: ios, swift

My date format in string is "2019-03-28".

My date formatter is like "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
let assignDate = dateFormatter.date(from: deliveryDate)
```

What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
let assignDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-03-28")
print("assignDate \(assignDate)")
```

All works fine for me here!

assignDate Optional(2019-03-28 00:00:00 +0000)

Comment: Its returning nil for me.

Comment: can you please put the date in code without variable and test it. (I think that in your deliveryDate isn't a format that you wait)

Comment: I have looked upon my data its coming as 2019-03-28. When I do this without a variable it is getting the date. Why is that happening?

Comment: try to print a deliveryDate before putting it to formatter. I think it is just deliveryDate is a empty String

Comment: so assignDate is a nil?

Comment: But let me clarify. It is OK if you will put hardcoded string instead of deliveredDate?

Comment: try printing assignDate and check its count.

Comment: I know that you provide the image, but can you please add a print with the delivered date? If it is working with hardcoded string but not working now - there is only one variable - delivered data. (Maybe it has some spaces or etc). Please print it before putting in formatter

Comment: Where you get this deliveredDate? can you provide peace of JSON (or whatever) when you get this? (I think is a has some strange signs)

Comment: @VishnuPrasannan check the string data `Data(assignDate.utf8)`

Comment: Guys it worked. I dont know what happened I just restart Xcode and now its running fine. Tons of thanks to both @AlexanderNikolaychuk

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
let assignDate = dateFormatter.date(from: deliveryDate)
```

This is working fine